# What would you use to implement a two stack queue ? An array based stack or linked list stack ? What about a two queue stack?

Tags: algorithm

I have thinking about the best stack implementation for a queue made using two stacks. Also, I have been thinking about the making of a stack implemented using two queues. I want to define the stack for a two-stacks queue and the queue for a two-queues stack. I have been dwelling on  which ADT to use for each ? Is it better to use an array based stack or linked list stack for a queue implemented using two stacks ? Also, is it better to use a array based queue or linked list based queue for a stack made with two queues ? What do you think is the best compromise in each of the two cases in terms of memory  and time ?

Comment: What if you placed the "stack bottoms" at both ends of _one_ array, growing the stacks to each other?

Comment: [Here](http://mendel.informatics.indiana.edu/~yye/lab/teaching/spring2014-C343/lists.php) is a succinct comparison of space/time complexity for array-based and linked lists. From there on the analysis for your 4 cases seems trivial.

Comment: "What would you use to implement a two stack queue ?" I've never encountered any implementation of a two-stack (two-queue) stack (queue). These are nice homework questions, but why on earth would you want to implement them this way?

Comment: Just for practice to get stronger with Algorithms and data structures

Comment: Also I do not have any problem implementing them. Just was checking which method is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say using an Array is the best.

Arrays use less space overhead (no "NEXT" Pointer etc.)
Also, performance is ought to be better as arrays are sequential and will utilize cache a-lot better.

either way, apart from Homework, implementation of Stack/Queue are well proven using arrays.